# Regular epimorphisms in the category of simple, undirected graphs

Tags: graph-theory, category-theory

Let $\textbf{Grph}$ be the category whose objects are graphs $G = (V,E)$ such that $V$ is a set and $E \subseteq \mathcal{P}_2(V) := \{\{a,b\} \subseteq V: a\neq b\}$. We sometimes write $E(G)$ for $E$. The morphisms are maps $f:G\to H$ such that whenever $\{v,w\}\in E(G)$ then $\{f(v),f(w)\}\in E(H)$.

How can regular epimorphisms in $\textbf{Grph}$ be characterized?

Comment: This question is slightly complicated by the fact that $\mathbf{Grph}$ does not have all coequalisers.

Comment: Oh ok - thanks for that remark...! Therefore I'm wondering whether the question is interesting for MO, or maybe it is just complicated (but not particularly interesting)